# Paypal: what form method should I use for a live site?

Tags: forms, paypal

In the [Paypal card verification example](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-pro/integration-guide/WPDPGettingStarted/#card-verification-example) it says:

> Important: **Never use post actions for live transactions; they are not
>   secure.**
>
> ```
> <form method=post action=https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp>
>   <input type=hidden name=USER value=...>
>   <input type=hidden name=PWD value=...>
>   <input type=hidden name=SIGNATURE value=...>
>   <input type=hidden name=VERSION value= 58.0>
>   <input type=hidden name=PAYMENTACTION value=Authorization>
>   <input type=hidden name=CREDITCARDTYPE value=Visa>
>   <input type=hidden name=ACCT value=...>
>   <input type=hidden name=STARTDATE value=112000>
>   <input type=hidden name=EXPDATE value=112020>
>   <input type=hidden name=CVV2 value=123>
>   <input type=hidden name=AMT value=0.00>
>   <input type=hidden name=CURRENCYCODE value=USD>
>   <input type=hidden name=FIRSTNAME value=...>
>   <input type=hidden name=LASTNAME value=...>
>   <input type=hidden name=STREET value=...>
>   <input type=hidden name=STREET2  value=>
>   <input type=hidden name=CITY value="San Francisco">
>   <input type=hidden name=STATE value=CA>
>   <input type=hidden name=Zip value=94121>
>   <input type=hidden name=COUNTRYCODE value=US>
>   <input type=hidden name=EMAIL value=... >
>   <input type=submit name=METHOD value=DoDirectPayment>
> </form>
> ```

I am confused, if the form method cannot be post (`<form method=post`) then what are we suppose to use? Wouldn't `get` be more insecure??? and I'm not aware of any other form methods besides `post` and `get`.

Comment: this is just an example to show you how to do the call. You will need to implement the code not in an html form but with some programming language

Comment: @jsabina the form Post will pass the info to my IPN file which is PHP.

Comment: "you should integrate cURL into your checkout pages"
you need to do the calls to the API as explained in the documentation for NVP as far as I know.. it is different from the old paypal standard with buttons.. that's why they wrote that the form in post it's ok just for test but it shouldn't be used Live